# Image as heigh as what's left of page

Tags: css, drupal

I have this simple navigation bar and an image view underneath. I want the image view's height to be as heigh as the amount of space  left without scrolling. If you get what I mean? I thought I could just set the `height` as `80%` or something but nothing changes.

Structure:

```
<div id="page">
<div id="navigation"></div>
<div id="content-container">here's my image view</div>
</div>
```

I want the `content-container`'s height to be what's left of the page. If I set my `page` 's height to `50%` nothing changes either..

This is the [website](http://www.photo-cress.com)

Edit: found it:

```
body, html{position:absolute; height:100%;}
#page{position:relative; height:100%;}
#content-container{height:89%;}
```

Comment: Try adding 100% to #page (or however you need), #nav to 11%, and then the #content-container to 89%. Think that would make it, even making a smaller % on the #page, because they are child from it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#navigation {
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
}
#content-container {
overflow:hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 70px; /* #navigation's height */
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```